# Unlisting multiple columns in R data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, double

I have a dataframe with values for multiple macro variables. When i compute log of the values and then the log differences it changes the variables into lists, causing problems with my script later on.

Example code:

```
#Compute log of relevant macrovariables
macro[,c("hp", "unem", "m1", "inc")] <- log(macro[,c("hp", "unem", "m1", "inc")])
colnames(macro)[2:5] <- paste(colnames(macro)[2:5], "log", sep = "_")

#Computing log differences
macro$ldiff_hp <- c(-diff(macro$hp_log), na.omit)
```

Im trying to unlist the columns and convert them to numeric with either of the following:

```
#Alternative 1
macro[,15:19]<- unlist(as.numeric(macro[,15:19]))
#Alternative 2
macro[,15:19] <- sapply(macro[,15:19],as.numeric)
```

It gives me the following error output:

```
> macro[,15:19]<- unlist(as.numeric(macro[,15:19]))
Error in unlist(as.numeric(macro[, 15:19])) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: Without being able to see the data in `macro`, you could try `apply(macro[,c("hp", "unem", "m1", "inc")],1, log)`. Otherwise, provide try and supply a sample of macro with `dput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `economics` dataset from `ggplot2` as example data and making use of `dplyr`s `lag` function the log differenced vars can be computed like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

macro <- ggplot2::economics

vars <- c("uempmed", "psavert")
vars_log <- paste(vars, "log", sep = "_")
vars_ldiff <- paste(vars, "ldiff", sep = "_")

#Compute log of relevant macrovariables
macro[, vars_log] <- sapply(macro[, vars], log)
# Lag values
macro[, vars_ldiff] <- sapply(macro[, vars_log], dplyr::lag)
# First Difference of logs
macro[, vars_ldiff] <- macro[, vars_log] - macro[, vars_ldiff]

macro
#> # A tibble: 574 x 10
#>    date         pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy uempmed_log psavert_log
#>    <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 1967-07-01  507. 198712    12.6     4.5     2944        1.50        2.53
#>  2 1967-08-01  510. 198911    12.6     4.7     2945        1.55        2.53
#>  3 1967-09-01  516. 199113    11.9     4.6     2958        1.53        2.48
#>  4 1967-10-01  512. 199311    12.9     4.9     3143        1.59        2.56
#>  5 1967-11-01  517. 199498    12.8     4.7     3066        1.55        2.55
#>  6 1967-12-01  525. 199657    11.8     4.8     3018        1.57        2.47
#>  7 1968-01-01  531. 199808    11.7     5.1     2878        1.63        2.46
#>  8 1968-02-01  534. 199920    12.3     4.5     3001        1.50        2.51
#>  9 1968-03-01  544. 200056    11.7     4.1     2877        1.41        2.46
#> 10 1968-04-01  544  200208    12.3     4.6     2709        1.53        2.51
#> # ... with 564 more rows, and 2 more variables: uempmed_ldiff <dbl>,
#> #   psavert_ldiff <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This seems to solve the list issue, thx! The only problem now is that it starts the difference calculation starting at the top (2018 in my dataset) and downwards to 1998, instead of at the bottom to the top. Do you know if i can apply something to make it count opposite direction (last observation now shows as NA instead of first obeservation showing as NA)? (This is why i had -diff in my original solution).

Comment: Sort your df by date, e.g. using dplyr's arrange `macro <- arrange(macro, date)` sorts the df by date in ascending order. Then it's in the right order for lag.